# How can I sentence compression with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

A: Quite good! Quite good! It works really well.
B: Quite good! It works really well.

How can I transfer A to B in Python? With which function?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: a = "".join(["".join(["".join([i for i in b]) for b in a]) for a in b]) should transform a into b ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most compact or robust but it works in your case and should be easy to follow and adjust to make it more reliable (e.g. If you use the word 'aardvark' you might end up with the same sentence but with 'ardvark' instead).

```
Sentence='Hey! Quite good! Quite good! It works really well.'

L=len(Sentence)
i=0
j=0
while i<L:
    j=i+1
    while j<L:
        wordlen=j-i
        if j+wordlen<L:
            if Sentence[i:j]==Sentence[j:j+wordlen]:
                print 'Original:',Sentence
                NewSentence=Sentence[:i]
                Sentence=NewSentence + Sentence[j:L]
                print 'Compressed:',Sentence
                i=L
                j=L
        j+=1
    i+=1
```